# AMD Catalyst 15.302 Build Failure on Ubuntu Server 14.04.05

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, glibc, amd-graphics

I'm trying to install the proprietary drivers for my Radeon R9 Fury graphics card. The files are fglrx_15.302, etc., and I'm getting them from [here at AMD Drivers](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064):

I'm installing on Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 using the instructions on the linked page.

After verifying the packages aren't already installed, I try to build them with (using * to avoid typing the very long filenames):

```
sudo dpkg -i fglrx_15.302* fglrx-core_15.302* fglrx-dev_15.302* \
fglrx-amdcccle_15.302*
```

The build output contains this line:

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-38-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/fglrx-core/15.302/build/make.log for more information
```

The log shows 2 errors in the file *firegl_public.c*:

```
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
    len=seq_printf(m, "%d\n", major);

error: 'XSTATE_FP' undeclared (first use in this function)
    if (!(fpu->state.xsave.header.xfeatures & XSTATE_FP))
```

So, the build is failing because of errors in that file

Looking at the Release Notes on the linked page, I see that my kernel (4.4) is outside their recommended range (2.6 to 3.19), and that my version of glibc is 2.19, which is outside their recommended range of 2.2 or 2.3. Normally, I would proceed by updating the kernel and glibc: however, that would roll back the kernel quite a ways, and (from Googling) I haven't found a way to install glibc 2.2 on 14.04 other than building it from source.

My question is: should I bite the bullet and update them anyway, or is this unlikely to solve the problem (and if so, what do I do now)?

Answer (score 0):

OP here. I ended up downloading on older version of the drivers (15.2) from AMD's website and doing a clean install. It failed with one error, which was that the compiler couldn't find the file *i387.h*. On my kernel, this is because that file was renamed *api.h*, and moved to a different directory by the Linux team (obviously since the driver package had been built). I found it here:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.40-42-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/fpu/api.h
```

At first, I renamed it to *i387.h* and moved it to the */asm* directory, where the package expected it. That fixed the error, but I also got other #include errors for *mman.h*, *poll.h*, and *ioctl32.h*. The first two files have also moved since the package build, while I can't find *ioctl32.h* at all (and am not even sure I need it for a 64-bit build).

Right now, I'm trying to decide whether to move the other 2 headers and see if it builds without *ioctl32.h*, or go into the package and change the #include statements to the correct locations (which is probably the right way to do it, but also a big pain).